# Oracle Sql update multiple records at once?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to Update multiple records in one sql query?
so update the status of all printers with id **A** and ip **1.1.1.1** to working (true), and all other as not working  (false)
So basically combining these two query together into one query:

```
update printers set status = true ,row_update_date =sysdate where printer id = 'A' and printer ip = '1.1.1.1'
update printers set status = false ,row_update_date =sysdate where printer id = 'A' and printer ip != '1.1.1.1'
```

table structure:

```
printers table:

printer ID,printer ip, status,row_update_date 
A         ,1.1.1.1   ,
A         ,1.1.1.2   ,
A         ,1.1.1.3   ,
A         ,1.1.1.4   ,
B         ,1.1.2.1   ,
B         ,1.1.2.2   ,
```

**UPDATE**
I forgot row_update_date !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
update printers 
set status = CASE WHEN printer ip = '1.1.1.1' THEN true ELSE false END
    ,row_update_date = SYSDATE
where printer id = 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you for that, i forgot to add row_update_date on all records, is it possible to do?

Comment: @user648026 Yes, you could update multiple columns at once

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [`decode`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) for Oracle's SQL for `switch-case` type statements

```
update printers 
   set status = decode(printer_IP,'1.1.1.1','true','false'),
       row_update_date = sysdate
 where printer_ID = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `UPDATE` with `CASE WHEN`

```
update printers 
set status = (CASE WHEN  printer ip = '1.1.1.1' 
                        THEN true
                   WHEN  printer ip != '1.1.1.1' 
                        THEN false 
              END)
WHERE printer id = 'A'
```